# iPad uses default.png as splash screen in universal app

Tags: ios, xcode, screen, default, splash-screen

I have

```
Default.png 
Default@2x.png 
Default-Portrait~ipad.png
```

(my app only supports portrait orientation)

as splash screens for my universal application. For some reason, when running app on iPad,  splash screen image seems twice as wide, twice as tall.

Not sure but it might be an XCode problem as well.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use of Default.png is no longer recommended.

What resolution are your files?

Please see:
http://phunkwerk.posterous.com/ipad-managing-multiple-launch-images-aka-defa

Comment: But xcode renames my images as "Default" when i use them as splash screen image. ("Summary" tab of project on xcode)

Comment: Have you tried just dragging the files into XCode and building rather than using the Summary tab?